# doxygen: /include working, but not /ref

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to link an internal file with "\ref test.hpp", but it's not working.  But, using "\include test.hpp" will work.  So does using snippets, just not linking the actual file.  The file path for "test.hpp" is included in the EXAMPLE_PATH variable, EXTRACT_ALL is set to "YES", and "@file" is included in "test.hpp".  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Aw, figured it out.  To link the file, all I have to do is exclude the "\ref" and the file "test.hpp" is automatically linked